# JavaScript objects update function not working

Tags: javascript

im studying JavaScript and im trying to solve the problem in this test exercise:
[FreeCodeCamp Record Collection](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection)

I can't understand why it doesnt work. The object details and the problem description are in the link above.

```
function updateRecords(object, id, prop, value) {
  if (value === '') {
    delete object[id][prop];
  } else if (prop === 'tracks') {
    if (object[id][prop].hasOwnProperty('tracks') == false) {
      object[id][prop] = [value];
    } else if (value !== '') {
      object[id][prop].push(value);
    }
  } else if (prop !== 'tracks' && value !== '') {
    object[id][prop] = value;
  }
  return object;
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
// running tests
After updateRecords(collection, 5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me"), tracks should have Take a Chance on Me as the last element.
After updateRecords(collection, 2468, "tracks", "Free"), tracks should have 1999 as the first element.
// tests completed
```

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
if (object[id][prop].hasOwnProperty('tracks') == false) {
```

If we replace the variables with their values, we get:

```
if (object[5439]['tracks'].hasOwnProperty('tracks') == false) {
                    ^                        ^
```

... which is always going to fail. Here is a simplified version:

```
function updateRecords(object, id, prop, value) {
  if (value === '') {
    delete object[id][prop];
  } else if (prop === 'tracks') {
    if (!object[id].hasOwnProperty('tracks')) {
      object[id][prop] = [];
    }
    object[id][prop].push(value);
  } else {
    object[id][prop] = value;
  }
  return object;
}
```